# Is “mon =” of any use in a bibtex file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, biber, multibib

In some of my bibtex entries I see the field `mon`, e.g.,

```
@Book{Abrial_96,
  author = {Jean-Raymond Abrial},
  title = {The {B}-Book},
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
  year = 2005,
  mon = nov
}
```

“mon” seems to be an abbreviation of “month”.
Is there any established, well-known package or program that processes the value of `mon` in a non-ignoring way? I don't recall typing in `mon` myself (except, hypothetically, to suppress printing out the month but saving the information internally in the source document for the future, though I don't remember such an intention of mine either). I looked into the documentation of certain bibliography-related programs and packages I typically use (bibtex, biblatex, natbib, biber, multibib) but failed to find any reference to “mon”.

Comment: I know of no bib style that understands the field `mon`, so it gets ignored.

Comment: anyone,  can write a bibtex style that uses that data it doesn't need a new program just a suitable style.

Comment: @egreg Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is data that could potentially be used by any bibtex style such as the one below, it does not need a different program.

[image]

`file.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Something about \cite{Abrial_96}.

\bibliographystyle{month}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bbook}

\end{document}
```

`bbook.bib`

```
@Book{Abrial_96,
  author = {Jean-Raymond Abrial},
  title = {The {B}-Book},
  publisher = "Cambridge University Press",
  year = 2005,
  mon = nov
}
```

`month.bst`

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    mon
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}

STRINGS { s t }
MACRO {nov} {"November"}

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}


FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}



FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\em " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


FUNCTION {format.mon}
{ mon empty$
    { "" }
    { "Who cares what year or by who, this was written in " mon *}
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title emphasize
}


FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.mon output
  new.block
  fin.entry
}


FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ 
  "\begin{thebibliography}{99}"  write$ newline$
}

READ

EXECUTE {begin.bib}

EXECUTE {init.state.consts}

ITERATE {call.type$}

FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

Comment: Though I meant established, well-known bibtex styles, your's is a good one :-). Thank you!

Comment: @AlMa1r the (slightly) serious point of the answer is that bib data lives forever and it may possibly be useful in the future even if nothing uses it now.

Comment: Right. In such a hypothetical future case, `mon` could be interpreted not necessarily as “month”, but, for example, as “monitor” or “money”, or even as the chemical formula “MoN” (even if the actual chemical substance is unstable or does not exist).